# Function to lookup arbitrary column in DataTable and return value in another arbitrary column

Tags: vb.net, types, datatable, lookup, datafield

I'm trying to write a generic function which can be used to look up an arbitrary value in an arbitrary column in an arbitrary `DataTable`, and return the corresponding value in another arbitrary column in the same `DataTable`. I'm not concerned with multiple values or multiple matches; the data is organised such that they don't occur anyway, all I want is for it to return the first match if it exists, or nothing if it doesn't.

I'm basing the code on this very simple example :

```
Private Function TableLookup(dtb As DataTable, lookupFieldName As String, lookupFieldValue As Integer, returnFieldName As String) As String

    Dim result As String
    Dim matches = From row In dtb Let lookup = row.Field(Of Integer)(lookupFieldName) Where lookup = lookupFieldValue
    If matches.Any Then result = matches.First().row.Field(Of String)(returnFieldName)
    Return result

End Function
```

But obviously that only works if the lookupField is an `Integer` field and the returnField is a `String` field. Because the function needs to handle arbitrary columns, those columns could have arbitrary `DataType`s? And the value being returned is also arbitrary (could be an `Integer`, could be a `String`... etc.)

Obviously I can determine what the `DataType`s are for each column easily enough :

```
Dim lookupFieldType As Type = dtb.Columns("lookupFieldName").DataType
Dim returnFieldType As Type = dtb.Columns("returnFieldName").DataType
```

But that's still no use as `row.Field(Of T)` is strongly-typed; I can't use a variable to specify the `DataType` :

```
Dim matches = From row In dtb Let lookup = row.Field(Of lookupFieldType)(lookupFieldName) Where lookup = lookupFieldValue
If matches.Any Then result = matches.First().row.Field(Of returnFieldType)(returnFieldName)
```

Have a feeling I'm going about this in completely the wrong way to begin with but it seems like there should be a straightforward way of looking up arbitrary columns in data tables (otherwise what's the point in having them, right?)

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you know what the final type is a priori, you could make the function generic in that type, and then that goes directly to `Field(Of T)`.  Otherwise, you might be looking at having to use reflection to build up your call at runtime---I haven't worked with generic routines before, but for classes, you can get the unspecialized type of e.g. `MyType(Of T)` as `GetType(MyType(Of ))`, and then use `MakeGenericType` to generate the specialized type.  I assume an analog exists for generic subs and functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will know what the types of both columns will be when you call the method, you can make it generic like this:

```vb
Private Function TableLookup(Of TKey As IEquatable(Of TKey), TResult)(table As DataTable,
                                                                      keyColumnName As String,
                                                                      key As TKey,
                                                                      resultColumnName As String) As TResult
    Dim row = table.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(Function(dr) dr.Field(Of TKey)(keyColumnName).Equals(key))

    Return If(row Is Nothing, Nothing, row.Field(Of TResult)(resultColumnName))
End Function
```

This method might be called like so:

```vb
Dim name As String = TableLookup(Of Integer, String)(myDataTable,
                                                     "Id",
                                                     id,
                                                     "Name")
```

If you won't know what the column types are, you could use something like this:

```vb
Private Function TableLookup(table As DataTable,
                             keyColumnName As String,
                             key As Object,
                             resultColumnName As String) As Object
    Dim keyType = key.GetType()

    If keyType IsNot table.Columns(keyColumnName).DataType Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Dim filterExpression As String

    If keyType Is GetType(String) Then
        filterExpression = $"{keyColumnName} = '{key}'"
    ElseIf keyType Is GetType(Date) Then
        filterExpression = $"{keyColumnName} = #{key:M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt}#"
    Else
        filterExpression = $"{keyColumnName} = {key}"
    End If

    Dim row = table.Select(filterExpression).FirstOrDefault()

    Return If(row Is Nothing, Nothing, row(resultColumnName))
End Function
```

Comment: Nice, thanks @jmcilhinney! Second option is working nicely; I would know the datatypes on calling though so would like to play around with option #1 just to get a better understanding of it. Question I have is, how would I _call_ such a function? i.e., what does one _pass_ as parameter for `(Of TKey As IEquatable(Of TKey), TResult)` in the first parentheses?